# What is the Cost Price of a Commodity which has a Loss of 2%

Tags: percentages, word-problem

When a commodity is sold for \$34.80, thre is a loss of 2%. What is the cost price of the commodity?

The answer choices are as follow:

\$26.10

\$43

\$43.20

\$46.40

I tried to solve this by multiplying 34.80 dollars  to 98 percent
(since there is a loss of 2%) and get $34.104.

But the answer key states that the answer is \$46.40.

Cost Price = (100/75 x 34.80) which yields \$46.40.

I don't know how it ended up with 100/75 in the solution, or how there's even 75 in it. I suspect the problem has some kind of typographical error.. Or if none, how did it wind up as $46.40?

Please help me understand this problem and reconcile the problem itself, the answer key I have and the solution I made earlier.
(My suspicion is that it has a typo error. It has a 25% loss not 2%.)

PS
I am a first yr college student struggling with word problems, specifically.

Thank you!

Answer (score 1):

$$\frac{34.8}{x}=\frac{98}{100}\implies x=\frac{34.8}{0.98}$$

Comment: I agree that the solution must have been that way. But the answer key suggests otherwise. I guess the problem itself has a faulty wording.. Like 2% should have been 25% in order to reconcile the solution in the answer key which states something like 100/75 x 34.80.

Comment: Don't worry then. Your calculations are ok the answer given is with $25\%$ of loss

Answer (score 1):

Yes, it must be a typo in the problem statement.

It makes no sense as written (with the given answers), but if we assume that the digit 5 has simply gone missing, both one of the answer options *and* the working in the answer key makes sense.

Answer (score 1):

If the loss is $2\%$, then you would need to *divide* by $0.98$.  If the cost is $C$ then you have
$$
\$34.80 = (98\% \text{ of }C)= 0.98C.
$$
So
$$
C=\frac{\$34.80}{0.98}.
$$
However, it does appear that $25\%$ rather than $2\%$ was intended.